# Passing DateTimes between Coldfusion and Database

Tags: sql-server, datetime, coldfusion

I'm a little confused as to how datetimes work on Coldfusion and MSSQL

I have building a forgotten password functionality that creates a temporary password that can only be used within 24 hours.

So, when the user requests a new temporary password, I'm creating a new password and setting the time when it was requested:

```
<cfset datetime = CREATEODBCDATETIME( Now() ) />
```

And then I put the time into the database

```
UPDATE users
SET 
    tempPassword = '#newPassword#'
    tempPasswordCreated = #datetime#
WHERE login = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.login#">
```

Then when the user tries to login in with the temporary password, I'm checking if less than 24 hours have elapsed.

```
<if checkAccounts.tempPassword eq form.password AND DateDiff("h", checkAccounts.tempPasswordCreated, CREATEODBCDATETIME( Now())) lt 24> 
    <!--- Login Code here--->
</cfif>
```

However,

```
DateDiff("h", checkAccounts.tempPasswordCreated, CREATEODBCDATETIME( Now()))
```

is outputting 12 where it has only been a few minutes since I submitted the form.

Comment: `now()` creates an ODBC date time, try using just `now()`

Comment: also what is data type is your `tempPasswordCreated` field? You should be using a `cfqueryparam` when adding that and `tempPassword` to the database

Comment: tempPasswordCreated is a datetime field. tempPassword is a randomly generated string, so using cfqueryparam is unnescessary

Comment: Protection against sql injection is only a side benefit. The primary purpose of cfqueryparam is to enhance performance through the usage of [bind variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bind_variable). Side note, `now()` already returns a datetime object. Wrapping it in `CreateODBCDateTime()` is redundant.

Comment: Did you notice you're missing a comma in the `SET` clause?

Comment: I suspect that is not the actual code you are using... because the above works fine once you fix the missing comma. Perhaps you are using CreateODBCDate instead of CreateODBCDateTime, or pulling the wrong record.  Dump the `checkAccounts` query. What is the value of `tempPasswordCreated`  and `login`?

Comment: @Leigh, the missing comma was because I had to sanitize my code a bit before posting it here and missed a comma.

Comment: @DavidFaver, Yes, it was working, but it was getting rounded by something.

Comment: (Edit) *was getting rounded by something* That is why it is important to post the actual code involved. There is nothing wrong with the above, aside from the comma. Creating a stand alone example can often help you catch that kind of issue on your own. Since it turned out to be a localized issue, having nothing to do with the code above, voting to close.

Comment: The stated problem was unexpected results.  The missing comma would have thrown an error.  I see no need to close the question.

Comment: No, the stated problem was *"DateDiff .. is outputting 12 where it has only been a few minutes since I submitted the form. "*. Had the above been their *actual* code, a sql error would have occurred before the DateDiff ever executed. Aside from the comma, the actual code they posted works exactly as intended. Even without cfqueryparam. So the real issue has nothing to do with what was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more simplified version that should work for you:

```
UPDATE users
SET 
    tempPassword = <cfqueryparam value="#newPassword#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    , tempPasswordCreated = <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
WHERE login = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.login#">
```

=

```
<cfif checkAccounts.tempPassword eq form.password 
    AND DateDiff("h", checkAccounts.tempPasswordCreated, now()) lt 24> 
    <!--- Login Code here--->
</cfif>
```

This is making the assumption that you are using some sort of date/time field type.

Comment: Personally I would use sql server's getdate() function as opposed to passing coldfusion's now().

Comment: Dan, I also use GETDATE() more often than not. That is beyond this scope however because you have to think about possible timezone and time sync issues.